# Jquery UI dialog conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change the format of a Jquery UI dialog box dynamically. I have an array and depending on the "format" parameter I pass to the createDialog function, the class should change ("green" class for "good", "red" class for "bad"):

```
var array = [["bullet1","bad"],["bullet2","good"], ["bullet3","bad"],["bullet4","good"]];

$('#a-button').click(function() {
var current = 0;
//current dynamically changes in the longer version of the code
var format = array[0][1];
createDialog(array[current][0], current, format);
});

function createDialog(data, current, format) {
var $div = $('<div>');
$div.html(data).dialog({

//condition I add which breaks the page
if (array[current][1] == "bad") { format = "red";
} else {
format = "green";
}

dialogClass: format,
width:"auto",

});
}
```

For reference my CSS is as follows:

```
.ui-dialog.red {
border: 3px solid red;
}

.ui-dialog.green {
border: 3px solid green;
 }
```

Could anyone give me the right syntax to add this condition without breaking the code please (the code will work if you remove the condition)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ternary operator` to make dialogClass a statement

```
function createDialog(data, current, format) {
var $div = $('<div>');
$div.html(data).dialog({
   dialogClass: array[current][1] == "bad"?"red":"green",
   width:"auto",
});
}
```